# getExternalFilesDir(null) returns null even with READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission

Tags: android, android-permissions

When I only declare READ_EXTERNAL_PERMISSION in my manifest, getExternalFilesDir() returns null. If I declare WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, getExternalFilesDir() returns something.

I did some check to see if I really have the permission, and checked if external storage is mounted.

```
PackageManager pm = mContext.getPackageManager();
int permRead = pm.checkPermission( Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, mContext.getPackageName() );
//permRead: "0"
int permWrite = pm.checkPermission( Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, mContext.getPackageName()); 
//permWrite: "-1"
String extState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
// extState: "mounted"

if ( permRead == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED 
    && extState.equals( Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED ) )
{
    File dir = mContext.getExternalFilesDir( Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES );
    // dir is null here!!
    ... more work...
}
```

As I understand it, I only need READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE to get something out of getExternalFilesDir().

What's could be the cause?

PS. My test device is LG Optimus Pro G with Android 4.1.2, and I rebooted the device.

Answer (score 2):

This is a note from the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)):

> Returns null if external storage is not currently mounted so it
>   could not ensure the path exists;

You can use [Environment.getExternalStorageState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageState()) to check it's state.

One common situation where the external storage is not available/mounted for apps is when the device is connected through the USB to a computer. The external storage becomes unavailable to the device while it is mounted on the computer.

Comment: I added a line to call Environment.getExternalStorageState(), and I got "mounted". But getExternalFileDir() still returns null.

Comment: The thing is, if I declare WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in the manifest, getExternalFileDir() returns something. If I only declare READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, getExternalFileDir()  returns null.

Answer (score -1):

This is because the docs say that any app that declares the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is implicitly granted the read permission as well.

Comment: I know that WRITE_EXTERNAL grants READ_EXTERNAL. The situation is that getExternalFileDir() should return something with READ_EXTERNAL, but it's not. It only returns something when I have WRITE.

Comment: That what i am saying to you , you must give WRITE permission too

Comment: The [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)) says _"To access paths belonging to other packages, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and/or READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE are required."_ It sounds like READ is sufficient.

Comment: External files are not always available: they will disappear if the user mounts the external storage on a computer or removes it.
There is no security enforced with these files. For example, any application holding WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE can write to these files.

Comment: That makes sense, but it doesn't seem to apply to my situation because I'm checking to see if the external storage is mounted as in `&& extState.equals( Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED ) `